# Visual Studio profile a running process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, profiler

VS2015 on Windows 10.
I want to profile an already-running process, a service.   I've done this in the past, I guess in older versions of VS, but I can't find the option now.  I do have an option to profile a running Windows Store app, but that's not my situation.

What am I missing?